# tesseract-ocr on Mac vscode does not work

Tags: macos, ocr, python-tesseract

```
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os
# Provide the path to the input image
image_path = '/Users/samuellee/inquiry/image1.png'
# Load the image using PIL (Python Imaging Library)
image = Image.open(image_path)
# Set the path to the Tesseract executable
tesseract_path = '/opt/homebrew/bin/tesseract'
# Check if the Tesseract executable exists
if not os.path.exists(tesseract_path):
    raise FileNotFoundError('Tesseract executable not found at: {}'.format(tesseract_path))
# Set the path to the Tesseract executable in pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = tesseract_path
# Perform OCR using Tesseract
recognized_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
# Print the recognized text
print(recognized_text)
```

I ran this code in vscode, and it does not give any errors but it does not print any text neither. It gives empty string.